# How to act based on a styled image is generated?

Tags: 7, media

three image styles defined: thumb, medium and large. 
By uploading an image, its thumb/medium/large copies are not generated. .    each styled copy of image is generated only when specific style is asked to be viewed.

I want to do something after styled copy is generated. For example, I want to upload medium size of image to my other server with my API copyToMyServer().

How may I do so? Couldn't find hook for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
http://happypixels.com/blog/triggering-creation-imagecache-derivatives-programmatically

Also see the trigger module.
http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger

You can add your desired action to trigged.

Comment: thanks for the reference, but it is for D6.